# Entity Framework grouped query translated into multiple SELECTs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Can someone help and tell me why this LINQ query is being translated in EF to multiple SELECTs ?

```
var query = db.ReportedFulfillments.GroupBy(x => x.ContractId).Select(grouping => new
    {
         ContractId = grouping.Key,
         Total = grouping.Count(),
         FU = grouping.Count(x => x.Month == 1 && x.Value == 1),
         BR = grouping.Count(x => x.Month == 1 && x.Value == 2)
    }
```

[image]

I thought that EF will output something like this:

```
SELECT ContractId,
 Count(*) AS Total,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 AND [Value] = 1 THEN Value END) AS FU,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 AND [Value] = 2 THEN Value END) AS BR,
FROM ReportedFulfillments GROUP BY ContractId
```

I'm using EntityFramework 6.2.0

Comment: Each WHERE/WHEN needs it own SELECT.

Comment: Please post the LINQ query as code instead of screenshot.

Comment: @jdweng why each WHERE/WHEN needs own SELECT ?  why EF doesnt translate such things to the SQL which I pasted at the end ? it seems simple

Comment: Translating an expression tree into SQL isn't trivial, at all. We should cut EF some slack when it doesn't come up with something a human being would write. And that's all there is to it when it comes to the "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, LINQ conditional `Count` of the `GroupBy` grouping result set is not supported very well (the SQL you expect relies on SQL `COUNT(expr)` which excludes NULLs and has no LINQ equivalent).

But the equivalent conditional `Sum` is supported and translated just well, so instead of

```
FU = grouping.Count(x => x.Month == 1 && x.Value == 1),
BR = grouping.Count(x => x.Month == 1 && x.Value == 2)
```

use

```
FU = grouping.Sum(x => x.Month == 1 && x.Value == 1 ? 1 : 0),
BR = grouping.Sum(x => x.Month == 1 && x.Value == 2 ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan ! Your solution works and it helped me to reduce the query execution time from ~5-6 sec. to 0.5 sec. I still find it strange that SUM works in this case and COUNT doesn't but okay maybe it will change in the future.